# DateTime.ParseExact And making it work with a custom format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datetime coming back from an text file as a string in the format:

> Saturday 15-07-2016 00:55:54

as in

> "dddd dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

I am trying to convert it to DateTime format using the DateTime.ParseExact, my code is as following:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string lastLine = File.ReadLines("logon.txt").Last(); //the date string is in the logon.txt
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(lastLine, "dddd dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",provider); 
return dt;
```

the exception i get is a System.FormatException : {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}

link to logon txt : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1oTQq97VF44Z21pT2FzM01XbU0/view?usp=sharing

any ideas?

Comment: you are passing the entire line to date parse method. is the file contains only date value?

Comment: yes. i will add the logon.txt.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to make sure `lastLine` contains what you think it contains?

Comment: i have. last lineLine contains : Saturday 15-07-2016 00:55:54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the date you're showing is Friday, but the string says it should be Saturday. Change the content of the file so instead of "Saturday" it says "Friday" and it should work. It does for me, anyway.

Alternatively, you could change the date part to "16-07-2016" and leave the day of the week "Saturday". Either way it should work.

Here's the code that works for me:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string lastLine = "Friday 15-07-2016 00:55:54";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(lastLine, "dddd dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", provider);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

It prints out:

> 7/15/2016 12:55:54 AM

Comment: You're right. tried to change it to Friday (saved it in the logon.txt OC), however no luck. still the same exception.

Comment: Try replacing the file contents with just a string. Something is wrong somewhere because it works perfectly fine for me. Maybe you have a leading space in the file or something.

Comment: Maybe it's because i'm changing it manually?? what i mean is, i'm testing it, and changing the dddd and the dd to yesterday, as in Friday and the 15th.

Comment: @Daniel I added the code that works for me to my answer. Give it a shot.

Comment: Just to confirm, code works for me too. It's because Saturday 7/15/2016 is an impossible date, the built in parser throws the exception

Comment: It is working. But the thing is, i was changing the txt file manually. and for unknown reason it is throwing the exception.

Comment: Silly question but is the text file being saved and retrieved (as opposed to a cached version)? Can you confirm that, in the debugger, the value of `lastLine` is the string expected and not other data/empty line?

Comment: I confirm that it is the string in lastLine is the string expected.